# how to run two requests sequentially in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Need some help on Jmeter for the following scenario please I need to simulate these steps in order to load our application.
a) make a request to a web-service.(done)
b) verify the response for some variables and extract a URL address from the response.(done)
c) Now using the extracted URL need to make another request.(extraction done)
d) in response a media file will be sent. 
My Plan consists of "stepping thread group-->(Sampler 1)HTTP Request +couple of listeners for data gathering--> (Sampler 2)HTTP Request +couple of listeners for data gathering. the issue is that when i ran the plan the first sampler generated 4 requests but the second one generated only 2 can you tell me why is it so.
In general how can i simulate all 4 steps in one go for a single thread. I hope that i have cleared myself.

Comment: As far as I know, jmeter works sequentially. what you need it preprocessors and postprocessors for doing the correlation and substitution stuff. I would suggest read about regex/beanshell postprocessor/preprocessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JMeter each thread runs requests [sequentially](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) already.

So in order to do what you expect you'll need to use:

- Post Processors called extractors to extract data into variables
- Variables to inject in the requests

Read:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#postprocessors
- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#functions